# Nvidia-settings resolution

Tags: display-resolution, nvidia-settings

I needed to update to nvidia-346 to play a game which requires newer drivers. However, after installing (from repositories) and restarting, my 1080p resolution was gone from the options in nvidia-settings.

I tried installing nvidia-352 and I get a few more resolution options, but still no 1080p. Please help!

xorg.conf file:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 352.21  (buildd@lcy01-07)  Thu Jun 18 12:03:14 UTC 2015

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: builtin, VertRefresh source: builtin
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "DFP-1"
HorizSync       28.0 - 55.0
VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GTX 960"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "1360x768 +0+0; nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25410/discussion-on-question-by-segata-nvidia-settings-resolution).

Answer (score 0):

I recently created [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/resolutionx/) program. It is a `randr` front-end that creates a new resolution mode, sets it, saves the selection and remains the same on reboot.

If that doesn't work for you, then google your monitor name, note the sync and refresh rates and place them into the `xorg.conf` file.

Comment: This sounds amazing! However, I'm getting the "unable to satisfy dependencies" error with the .deb file. Any way you could post the packages needed to I can install them through the terminal?

Comment: @Segata I have, I think, fixed the problem - redownload the package and try again...

Comment: @Segata Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I changed monitors and all the problems went away. Basically, the Nvidia drivers or X weren't recognising my monitor.

Obviously this is far from ideal for most people if they haven't got a spare monitor lying around or money to buy another one, but I also never worked out how to get 1080p or sound through HDMI.

The monitor worked fine previously, but after the driver update it stopped working and I was unable to find the versions of the packages which worked with that monitor (which I had used for 4 years on Linux with an Nvidia card without problems).